# Web browser dont open any file type in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am using WebBrowser to display the document(.pdf, .docx files) in iOS codenameone. It was working fine in iOS12 and older version. But, now when I build it again, it displays blank form in older version and even in iOS 13. But, if I set URL to "https//:www.google.com" works fine. Below is the code which demonstrates that. Please help me out with this. As users are effected by this now. Thanks

```
FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    String urlPath = fss.getAppHomePath()  + filename;

    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    Form f= new Form();
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);
    wb.setURL(urlPath);
    f.show();
```

Comment: Why are you using `WebBrowser`? It's deprecated, normally you should use `BrowserComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Apple started sending out developer warnings about using `UIWebView` so we switched the default to use `WKWebView` as we explained back in [this article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/wkwebview.html).

At this particular moment you can still toggle back to `UIWebView` as right now it's just a warning but that might become a problem.